# How to add second node in NosDB opensource?

Tags: powershell, distributed-database, database-cluster, nosdb, nosql

I am trying [NosDB](http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/), created database cluster on single node, and than added second node in my database cluster, but I am failing with error message, "Add-Shard : Login 'asif_mehmood' does not exist".
Steps I perforemd:

- Installed NosDb OpenSource on two boxes.
- Created cluster with one shard on first box, using New-DatabseCluster powershell cmmdlet.
- Added another shard with second box as node, using Add-shard powershell cmdlet.
- Failed with following error Message

> Add-Shard : Login 'asif_mehmood' does not exist
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-Shard -Name shard2 -Server 192.168.0.15 -Port 2250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding other node in database cluster, both nodes should be in same domain or on same work group,
before adding second node in database cluster, add login of current box on second box using Add-Login cmmdlet with following parameters

- Username: username of second box windows login
- Password: Password for above
- Server: IP of second box,

After adding login second node was added successfully in database cluster.